# Making a ghost filled animation button and having issue with border radius

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to fill a button when hovered in an animated way which is working just fine. I use the :before css prop to created an animated div to fill the button when hovered. My problem right now is that I have a border-radius on the button and the same exact border-radius on the :before div, but they do not match up.

```
<div class="flex">
  <button href="#0" class="bttn">Continue</button>
</div>
```

---

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700';

$font:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
$primary:#FF0072;

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0;
  font-family:$font;
  background: #F5F0FF;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.flex {
  min-height:50vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

button.bttn {
  color:$primary;
  border-radius: 22px;
  text-decoration:none;
  -webkit-transition:0.3s all ease;
  transition:0.3s ease all;
  &:hover {
    color:#FFF;
  }
  &:focus {
    color:#FFF;
  }
}

.bttn {
  font-size:18px;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  width:270px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:14px 0px;
  border:3px solid $primary;
  border-radius:2px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  &:before {
    -webkit-transition:0.5s all ease;
    transition:0.5s all ease;
    position:absolute;
     border-radius: 22px;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    right:50%;
    bottom:0;
    opacity:0;
    content:'';
    background-color:$primary;
    z-index:-1;
  }
  &:hover {
    &:before {
      -webkit-transition:0.5s all ease;
      transition:0.5s all ease;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      opacity:1;
    }
  }
  &:focus {
    &:before {
      transition:0.5s all ease;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      opacity:1;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a codepen to show what I currently have.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvxLKp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a :before with the wrong sizing: I'm not sure how this comes but I know a way how to solve this. Your border is inreasing your button size. Unfortunately this size won't add up on your :before size. You can calculate this size (3px in your case) and add this size negative on your right and left.

```
&:hover {
    &:before {
        -webkit-transition:0.5s all ease;
        transition:0.5s all ease;
        left: -3px;
        right: -3px;
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

You can do the same for the focus state

Answer (score 1):

Remove the border radius from your :before pseudo and add an overflow: auto to your button.

What's happening is the :before pseudo is positioning inside of the button and not the full size including the border.

Alternatively you could position your before pseudo differently such as top: -3px, left: -3px, right: -3px, bottom: -3px;